# DatePickerDialog UI under API22 is cutting information out

Tags: android, material-design, datepickerdialog, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using the default DatePickerDialog:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                }
                            }, year, month, day);

                    datePickerDialog.show();
```

With the following theme

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

  </style>
```

Which is displaying fine in my virtual device under API 29. However, under API 22 there are some display issues.

[image]
Green part on the left does not go all the way down, and the name of the month is not fully displayed at the top

[image]
Everything is correct

Additionally, in API 29, if the space to display is not big enough, the calendar will change to this:
[image]

My question is: without using an external library (I have already seen some that I am tempted on trying), is there any way to correct this on API 22? The UI seems just bad, I don't understand why this would be an option but maybe I am just choosing the wrong theme.

Comment: It's fine to use 3rd party libraries. Have you tried this one? https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: This is the one I was checking out: https://github.com/Gericop/DateTimePicker, but thanks for the suggestion